# uploaded file contents are not available in chrome.webRequest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In a chrome extension, I'm trying to get the data of every uploaded file by inspecting `requestBody.raw` inside `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`. however, by testing file upload to various sites it seems that the file contents are not there. for example, when uploading a PDF file to Gmail my extension is called 3 times with POST request, but in all of those requests `requestBody.raw` array size is 0. in other sites sometimes `requestBody.raw` is filled but not with the uploaded file's contents.

**Edit:** Follows are the full scripts. I tried to inspect all possible data:

manifest.json:

```
 {
     "name": "Example",
     "version": "1.0",
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "description": "Example",
     "permissions": ["webRequest","webRequestBlocking","nativeMessaging","*://*/*"],
     "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]}
 }
```

background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
        if(details.method != "GET"){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(details));

            if(details.requestBody && details.requestBody.raw){
                for(var i = 0; i < details.requestBody.raw.length; ++i){
                    if(details.requestBody.raw[i].file){
                        console.log("FILE");
                        console.log(details.requestBody.raw[i].file);
                    }
                    if(details.requestBody.raw[i].bytes){
                        console.log("RAW");
                        console.log(details.requestBody.raw[i].bytes.byteLength);
                        var dv = new DataView(details.requestBody.raw[i].bytes);
                        var result = "";
                        for(var j = 0; j < dv.byteLength; ++j){
                            result += (String.fromCharCode( dv.getInt8(j) ));
                        }
                        console.log(result);
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
        return {cancel: false};
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "requestBody"]
);
```

This is the output when uploading test.txt with the text "hello" to dropbox:

```
background.js:5 {"frameId":0,"method":"POST","parentFrameId":-1,"requestBody":{"formData":{"_subject_uid":["144107656"],"fq_dir":[""],"is_xhr":["true"],"ns_map":["231317524_1599"],"show_deleted":["false"],"t":["TUN_gKxY2VWUVyTKF6-L551T"]}},"requestId":"53563","tabId":1207,"timeStamp":1478512776308.165,"type":"xmlhttprequest","url":"https://www.dropbox.com/update/list_dir"}
background.js:5 {"frameId":0,"method":"POST","parentFrameId":-1,"requestBody":{"formData":{"_subject_uid":["144107656"],"fq_path_prefix":["/"],"include_inherited":["false"],"is_xhr":["true"],"max_results":["5"],"sort_by_name":["false"],"t":["TUN_gKxY2VWUVyTKF6-L551T"]}},"requestId":"53564","tabId":1207,"timeStamp":1478512776682.595,"type":"xmlhttprequest","url":"https://www.dropbox.com/share_ajax/shared_with"}
background.js:5 {"frameId":0,"method":"POST","parentFrameId":-1,"requestBody":{"formData":{"_subject_uid":["144107656"],"is_xhr":["true"],"paths":["[\"/test.txt\"]"],"t":["TUN_gKxY2VWUVyTKF6-L551T"]}},"requestId":"53565","tabId":1207,"timeStamp":1478512776685.152,"type":"xmlhttprequest","url":"https://www.dropbox.com/sm/get_token_info"}
background.js:5 {"frameId":0,"method":"POST","parentFrameId":-1,"requestBody":{"raw":[{"bytes":{}}]},"requestId":"53566","tabId":1207,"timeStamp":1478512776688.215,"type":"xmlhttprequest","url":"https://www.dropbox.com/2/sharing/list_file_members/batch"}
background.js:14 RAW
background.js:15 49
background.js:21 {"files":["id:eIK7fjIt9xgAAAAAAAAAdw"],"limit":5}
background.js:5 {"frameId":0,"method":"POST","parentFrameId":-1,"requestBody":{"formData":{"_subject_uid":["144107656"],"activity_context":["3"],"activity_context_data_batch":["[\"/test.txt\"]"],"is_xhr":["true"],"t":["TUN_gKxY2VWUVyTKF6-L551T"]}},"requestId":"53567","tabId":1207,"timeStamp":1478512776690.839,"type":"xmlhttprequest","url":"https://www.dropbox.com/file_activity/comment_status_batch"}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Usually, including a *manifest.json*, some of the background *and* content scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: "Various" sites? Can you give examples other than Gmail?

Comment: google docs, dropbox

Comment: Did you expect to be able to inspect arraybuffer contents in the console log? :-) Unfortunately, it's not implemented. Use search to see examples of handling this data properly.

Comment: Still trying to figure this one out. It's working properly in Firefox, but in Chrome it returns an empty array. Sounds like a bug or a limitation.